# Is there a way to copy files from a network location while also providing the credientials to access that location using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am grand spanking new to python language, however decide to just jump into it and finding myself quickly learning the language. I developed a script that will help gather files from multiple network locations to help QA Tester's begin their testing on a clean machine fairly quickly. However I have hit an issue where if your on a Local Admin account on the machine, my script has issue trying to reach a particular network location, the error that i am receiving is The username or password is incorrect. I have done the following things to troubleshoot the issue:

- Verified that i can reach this location via File explorer.
- Verified that the address is correct in the script.
- Verified that the machine is on domain that should allow me to access these network locations.

My theory is that it is trying to use the Local Admin account cred's to access this network location which will obviously fail and produce the result.

***My question to you brilliant python programmers is if there is a way to copy files from a given location but also use the credentials i have given it in the script?***

I know you can ask the user for credentials but that is a route i would like to avoid as the script is suppose to be some what automated(least user interactivity the better!)

Here is an example of the code I am using, for privacy and agreement reasons i cannot post the actual network locations or any hint of these locations.

CODE:

```
#---------------NETWORK LOCATIONS----------#
gNetLoc = r'\\some_Machine_Address\folder1'

#----------------COPY FUNCTION-------------#
def rtSomething(path, des):
"""
This function is to retrieve any files or folders within the path given
Args:
    path: This is the source path which we want to copy files from
    des: This is the destination path which we want to copy files to
Returns: None

"""
try:
    myCopyTree(path, des)
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to copy over content, the following is the error message:")
    print(e)
    print(tb.format_exc())

#-----------COMMAND USED TO CALL COPY FUNCTION-----------#
rtSomething(gNetLoc, os.path.expandvars(r'%Public%\Public Desktop\QA_Folder'))
```

EDIT: (FORGOT TO ADD FUNCTION)
MY COPY TREE FUNCTION:

```
def myCopyTree(source, destination, include_empty_dirs=True):
    """
    Copy a tree of files and folders to a destination.

    Args:
        source (str): Path of the source files/folders.
        destination (str): Path to copy the files/folders to.
        include_empty_dirs (bool): Should we create empty folders. Defaults to True.
    """
    source = os.path.abspath(source)
    for p, ds, fs in os.walk(source):
        if include_empty_dirs:
            for d in ds:
                d_path = os.path.join(destination, p[len(source):], d)
                # Make dirs
                if not os.path.isdir(d_path):
                    print('Making {0}'.format(d_path))
                    os.makedirs(d_path)
        for f in fs:
            s_path = os.path.join(p, f)
            d_path = os.path.join(destination, p[len(source) + 1:], f)
            print('Copying {0} -> {1}'.format(s_path, d_path))
            # Make dirs
            if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(d_path)):
                print('Making {0}'.format(d_path))
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(d_path))
            # Copy the file
            shutil.copy(s_path, d_path)
```

Comment: Where is mCopyTree? Post its code

Comment: added the function

Comment: And where exactly you are giving username and password in this code? None of those brilliant coders can help you if you dont give exact error and show line where it occurred

Comment: No where, i was wondering if there is a way to provide the username and password in the script.

Comment: Essentially does python have a method that will allow me to specify a path and the credentials to that path?

Comment: On what line does it say you incorrect username and password?

Comment: the shutil.copy(s_path, d_path) in MyCopyTree. The reason behind this is because credientials it is using to access the given s_path is the cached credientials of the Local Admin account thus providing the error. I was wondering if there is a way i can have my script use credientials to access that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NET USE` command to mount the share to an available drive.

import os

```
os.system(r"NET USE D: \\some_Machine_Address\folder1 %s /USER:%s\%s" % (password, domain_name, user_name))
```

where D: is obviously available drive letter.

Also dont forget to umount it after using

```
os.system(r"NET USE D: /DELETE")
```

Alternative:
If you cant map to drive then get access to share using net use as:

```
winCMD = 'NET USE ' + networkPath + ' /User:' + user + ' ' + password
subprocess.Popen(winCMD, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Then copy as

```
shutil.copy2(networkPath + 'sourceDir/sourceFile', 'destDir/destFile')
```